# audio of Video play not synchronise properly

Tags: android, video

I am working on customized video play in android. I am using following code for video play.

```
mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();   
            mp.start();
            videoview.setVideoPath(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {              
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoview.start();                          
                }
            })
```

I am facing problem that sound repeats twice & so its mixing during video play. Can you please guide me what will be the issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting the same file twice, try the following...

```
        videoview.setVideoPath(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {              
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();                          
            }
        })
```